# How to initialize OrderedDictionary - Swift Collections

Tags: swift, swift-dictionary

Reading from the [github docs](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) I can see how to use it, but when I try to initialize it (to empty):

```
var responses: OrderedDictionary = [:]
```

it says: `Empty collection literal requires an explicit type`

I tried this:

`var responses: OrderedDictionary<String: <TransactionsDataItemsClassAModel>> = [:]`

but doesn't work, what's the proper way to initialize this?

This is how I have initialized my non ordered diccionary:

```
var dataDiccionary: [String: [TransactionsDataItemsClassAModel]] = [:]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular syntax for generic types is like `Array<T>` and `Dictionary<K, V>`

- There's short-hand syntax specific to `Array` and `Dictionary`: `[T]` and `[K: V]`.

You're confusing some things and combined the two into an an invalid middle-ground.

`OrderedDictionary` doesn't have any special short-hands, so you would just treat it like any other generic type. The generic type parameters are specified with a comma separated list:

```
OrderedDictionary<String, [TransactionsDataItemsClassAModel]>
```

Comment: I tried this: `var responses: OrderedDictionary<String, <TransactionsDataItemsClassAModel>> = [:]` but still doesn't work

Comment: @Arturo I didn't realize you also switched the `[ ]` to `< >`. I've edited my answer

Comment: Ohh I see how the syntax works, thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.